# OnClick Individual JavaScript Popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, popup

I am having a bit of trouble with this code that I have been playing with. I have it so that, at least so far, that a popup will show when a text is selected. The issue is that I cannot get it to work for all 4 so that I get 4 different pop ups, all the pop ups are connected to the first. I also am trying to get it so that the pop up shows under each button clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -250%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

</style>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center">

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">First Popup
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">This is the first pop up selected</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">second Popup
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">This is the second pop up selected</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">third Popup
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">This is the third pop up selected</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">Fourth Popup
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">This is the fouth pop up selected</span>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is how do I get it so that the pop ups show up properly under each text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You used the same id for every one of the popups. You can't do that. Each popup needs to have a unique id.

Comment: How would that look? In the Body HTML, would it just mean that each of the div classes are switched to their own id with their own styling?

Comment: Use a common class, not a common id, and set the styling for the class.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are unique selectors. Instead you have to use classnames for your purpose.

Also to figure out which popup heading you have clicked on, you can use  `event.currentTarget`

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  const currentlyVisible = document.querySelector('.popup .show');
  if(currentlyVisible) {
    currentlyVisible.classList.toggle('show');
  }
  var popup = event.currentTarget.querySelector('.popuptext');
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  
}

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -250%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(event)">First Popup
  <span class="popuptext" >This is the first pop up selected</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(event)">second Popup
  <span class="popuptext">This is the second pop up selected</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(event)">third Popup
  <span class="popuptext">This is the third pop up selected</span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(event)">Fourth Popup
  <span class="popuptext">This is the fouth pop up selected</span>
</div>
```

You might also want to look into hiding the popup already shown.

Comment: So far, this works best. I am using dreamweaver and I look at the end, and for whatever reason, it gives an error saying "the id value [myPopup] must be unique." Not sure what is causing that?

Comment: @jsLearnr You were repeating `id="myPopup"` on all of the popup texts. ID has to be unique. I have not included that in my code.